# Editing one function in GUIDE, changes all functions?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-guide

I am using Matlab's GUIDE for the first time, I am trying to edit one of the two push button functions (both open an image), but editing one changes all of them. Here is a bit of code:

```
% --- Executes on button press in Floating.
function Floating_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

clc;
axes(handles.axes1);
[Float, PathName, FilterIndex] = uigetfile('*.bmp');
if(Float ~= 0) 
    Floating = fullfile(PathName, Float);
    FloatArray = imread(Floating);
    imshow(FloatArray);
    axis on; 
end 

% Update handles structure
guidata(hObject, handles);

% hObject    handle to Floating (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)


% --- Executes on button press in Reference.
function Reference_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

clc;
axes(handles.axes2);
[Ref, PathName, FilterIndex] = uigetfile('*.bmp');
if(Ref ~= 0) 
    Reference = fullfile(PathName, Ref);
    ReferenceArray = imread(Reference);
    image(ReferenceArray); 
end 

% Update handles structure
guidata(hObject, handles);
```

For example,

```
image(ReferenceArray)
```

will open an image in RBG, but

```
imshow(FloatArray)
```

will open in grayscale (I also do not understand why that is). But my main concern is after opening up

```
imshow(FloatArray)
```

the other image will automatically turn grayscale. I am very confused... Also, as far as I know the images ARE already grayscale, at least they are when I open them in MS paint or ImageJ.

Comment: read the images in MATLAB (`img = imread('...')`) and post the output of `size(img)` and `class(img)` for both images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to explicitly specify the parent handle whenever you are doing GUI stuff. For example:

```
imshow(img, 'Parent',handles.ax1)
```

and

```
axis(handles.ax1, 'on')
```

---

As for images and colormaps, you should understand the [type of images](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/f14-13543.html) MATLAB supports (indexed vs. truecolor). Also note that a figure has only one colormap applied to all images, although there are [techniques](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-GNRWEH/index.html) to [overcome this](http://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2009/07/24/using-multiple-colormaps-in-a-single-figure/).

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much for the speedy reply! That answers all my questions. Thanks again!